# Why does authentication with RSA done with cryptography.io and java on android does not work together?

Tags: java, android, python, rsa

I want to use RSA to authenticate clients at a server. The server written in Python posesses the public key of the client which is an Android app. I decided to use cryptography.io on the Python side to encrypt a token and I want to decrypt it with javax.crypto.

I constructed a test case for my problem which works with Python3 and Java without Android: https://github.com/pinae/rsa-test-case

The Python side looks like this:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa, padding
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from base64 import b64encode

N = int("6118949884542035758228165150480970484775948540894875675750019196760430437326375788316244083667312" +
        "1127912691592042082374698218570305709542452573367037247942794176360141330260796114161991634877520" +
        "9318638985939797245838394186947432815805159715295950796093763256835288557638341359755154607092758" +
        "2125876646350225386205170869478762584625481559337889894643589498753324189655838737003231877149808" +
        "0769782782986004968223577252545632595856348578972986803087375151523130980468315658731145540661959" +
        "6050525545290045046944269076387765616800870979827653118293545195314596061160131055834487112435567" +
        "4188026149535089147013264878621144892167844471212662659174643958985053020651238408715157877344829" +
        "6332175379863190146700888623219388047354669492295105275244771100851445677743253407525918517909312" +
        "1064757322245873728715200541955720319721861626588734157728068815156326358980514571916869090216857" +
        "1674529819233099030185697193927748667568997849788205951188943230054712902846136235791743994018772" +
        "7474047360851939145847078056327450140607700002648843419498134708391530606499524381440473803469993" +
        "9125774781194053568746989605638413082541876600142556111173865505734416200456890738357199900214109" +
        "565602296409823349451352963303084528108078854673626645830490080013931")
e = 65537
key = rsa.RSAPublicNumbers(e, int(N)).public_key(default_backend())

token = "Some test bytes.".encode('utf-8')
encrypted_token = key.encrypt(
    token,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),
        label=None
    )
)
with open("token.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(b64encode(encrypted_token), encoding='utf-8'))
```

The java code is a bit more verbose:

```
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class RsaTest
{
    public static String readTokenFile() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("token.txt"));
        String everything;
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            everything = sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
        return everything;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BigInteger d = new BigInteger("295037637291191738956635211796692963240490064989667014592826352469032152" +
        "554302874575878226107217392868462250989293041036431894475130143513053896027950170894654313285696024572" +
        "555534662699797386157658559164375812029364988576033978927620169476835254057350243662602730036794048964" +
        "222696882434825511051317613969394699304819377647584836298910958813068451008480950615750481597424491969" +
        "616122089713036168262562790026376709519880676568817708332018002498979363533291261269633760290508292885" +
        "685631554642526071767451720995816315263034482926025947996376673879307443752926326504743341468067701663" +
        "647011041587666229832948060125468304864468556385524233326117655101116575438068518128417547551238351385" +
        "860308667178310273798307275716775496726007972420724941548071903190058191309574401221590126135595556423" +
        "538805604263913766128874929792845212075676240959916344274635408931764294117768329862724498717467735936" +
        "771182991195111736108715670105340851228608489685386356809638648591870140613333363474891211943508005174" +
        "556955182421433325620501790085286962409667669154804819913241047270891375736816718480232577171854082683" +
        "282930378415208382344040938073467357285325060767468878914840146155371082700586582168876180646622366892" +
        "654491190772272882871959076736231875073");
        BigInteger e = new BigInteger("65537");

        byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[]{};
        try {
            String encryptedToken = readTokenFile();
            encryptedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encryptedToken);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File token.txt was not found.");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IO error.");
        }
        RSAPrivateKeySpec privateKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(d, e);
        try {
            KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) factory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            byte[] token = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
            System.out.println(token);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            System.out.println("Missing algorithm.");
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException ex) {
            System.out.println("Invalid key spec.");
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
            System.out.println("No such padding.");
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            System.out.println("Invalid key.");
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
            System.out.println("Wrong block size.");
        } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
            System.out.println("Bad padding.");
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the code I get a BadPaddingException. I believe the settings for the padding match in both implementations.

I would prefer an answer which keeps my choices for libraries but I am open for all ideas how to get this running.

Comment: You're saying your code works on Oracle Java but not Android? Also, do you realize that if you're readToken() method throws a FileNotFoundException you continue on anyway and will then get a BadPaddingException? Try setting `byte[] encryptedBytes = null;` and see if you get a different error message.

Comment: I constructed this example because it creates the same problem I have with android with oracle java. Did you try to execute the example on your machine? If you execute the python part first the file exists and the java code reads its contents.

Comment: Sorry, looking at it again I see a simple mistake in the Java code at line `RSAPrivateKeySpec privateKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(d, e)`. This should be `new RSAPrivateKeySpec(N, d)` where the N is the same N as in the python code.

Comment: RSA is using a private and a public key. The private key consists of `d` and `e` while the public key consists of `N` and `e`. The public key is used in the Python code to encrypt the token and the private key is used on the Java side to decrypt it. Just for fun I tested your suggestion anyways and it produces no BadPadding exception. However the decrypted text is wrong.

Comment: I'm an expert on RSA and Java cryptography. I have made the corrections I recommended and run the code, and received correct results. There is another bug in your code, namely your assumption that `System.out.println(token);` prints out something meaningful. It does not. You would get something more meaningful with `System.out.println(new String(token, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

Comment: I tested your suggestion and it worked. I clearly misunderstood the `RSAPrivateKeySpec` class. Thank you for your help. You mad my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [JamesKPolk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/jameskpolk) pointed out there were two Bugs in my Code: The most important one was that `RSAPrivateKeySpec` needs the parameters `N` and `d` instead of `d` and `e`. The second error was not to convert the result to UTF-8.

I updated the repository of the example which contains working code now: https://github.com/pinae/rsa-test-case

Here is the working Java code for reference (The Python part did not need to be changed):

```
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class RsaTest
{
    public static String readTokenFile() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("token.txt"));
        String everything;
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            everything = sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
        return everything;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BigInteger d = new BigInteger("295037637291191738956635211796692963240490064989667014592826352469032152" +
        "554302874575878226107217392868462250989293041036431894475130143513053896027950170894654313285696024572" +
        "555534662699797386157658559164375812029364988576033978927620169476835254057350243662602730036794048964" +
        "222696882434825511051317613969394699304819377647584836298910958813068451008480950615750481597424491969" +
        "616122089713036168262562790026376709519880676568817708332018002498979363533291261269633760290508292885" +
        "685631554642526071767451720995816315263034482926025947996376673879307443752926326504743341468067701663" +
        "647011041587666229832948060125468304864468556385524233326117655101116575438068518128417547551238351385" +
        "860308667178310273798307275716775496726007972420724941548071903190058191309574401221590126135595556423" +
        "538805604263913766128874929792845212075676240959916344274635408931764294117768329862724498717467735936" +
        "771182991195111736108715670105340851228608489685386356809638648591870140613333363474891211943508005174" +
        "556955182421433325620501790085286962409667669154804819913241047270891375736816718480232577171854082683" +
        "282930378415208382344040938073467357285325060767468878914840146155371082700586582168876180646622366892" +
        "654491190772272882871959076736231875073");
        BigInteger e = new BigInteger("65537");
        BigInteger N = new BigInteger(
        "6118949884542035758228165150480970484775948540894875675750019196760430437326375788316244083667312" +
        "1127912691592042082374698218570305709542452573367037247942794176360141330260796114161991634877520" +
        "9318638985939797245838394186947432815805159715295950796093763256835288557638341359755154607092758" +
        "2125876646350225386205170869478762584625481559337889894643589498753324189655838737003231877149808" +
        "0769782782986004968223577252545632595856348578972986803087375151523130980468315658731145540661959" +
        "6050525545290045046944269076387765616800870979827653118293545195314596061160131055834487112435567" +
        "4188026149535089147013264878621144892167844471212662659174643958985053020651238408715157877344829" +
        "6332175379863190146700888623219388047354669492295105275244771100851445677743253407525918517909312" +
        "1064757322245873728715200541955720319721861626588734157728068815156326358980514571916869090216857" +
        "1674529819233099030185697193927748667568997849788205951188943230054712902846136235791743994018772" +
        "7474047360851939145847078056327450140607700002648843419498134708391530606499524381440473803469993" +
        "9125774781194053568746989605638413082541876600142556111173865505734416200456890738357199900214109" +
        "565602296409823349451352963303084528108078854673626645830490080013931");

        byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[]{};
        try {
            String encryptedToken = readTokenFile();
            encryptedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encryptedToken);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File token.txt was not found.");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IO error.");
        }
        RSAPrivateKeySpec privateKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(N, d);
        try {
            KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) factory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            byte[] token = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
            System.out.println(new String(token, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            System.out.println("Missing algorithm.");
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException ex) {
            System.out.println("Invalid key spec.");
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
            System.out.println("No such padding.");
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            System.out.println("Invalid key.");
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
            System.out.println("Wrong block size.");
        } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
            System.out.println("Bad padding.");
        }
    }
}
```